# How i can get tuple value (querydsl) since thymeleaf?

Tags: java, spring, tuples, thymeleaf, querydsl

i don'i know how i get the tuple value of queryDSL since thymeleaf

since backEnd i send this value:

```
List<Tuple> products = productServiceImpl.findProductByFiltersPaginate(null, 0, 1, null);

ModelAndView view = new ModelAndView();
        view.addObject("products",products);
        view.setViewName(ViewConst.MAIN_LAYOUT);
        view.addObject("view","catalog");
        return view;
```

but in front (thymeleaf) i dont know how to get the values. my code is the below:

```
<div th:each="product :${products}">
             <h2 th:text="${product}"></h2>
        </div>
    </div>
```

but i don't know what put after the name of the variable.
i already tried these ways:
${product.name}, ${product['name']}, ${product[0]} 
but none of them works.

if i put only this ${product} it returns me in this format each value

```
[39, Moto KTM DUKE, /images/products/product39/m_39_0.jpg]
```

Comment: What is the complete package for a Tuple?  How would you access the name in java? `products.get(0).???`

Comment: hi, since java i access like this 2 ways:  product.get(0, Product.class) or product.get(qProduct.title) . with your answer it returned this message EL1004E: Method call: Method get(java.lang.Integer) cannot be found on com.querydsl.core.types.QTuple$TupleImpl type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on what you replied with, I think these may work:

`product.get(0, Product.class)`

```
<!-- Note, you have to replace your.package.Product with the actual package -->
<div th:each="product :${products}" th:with="class=${T(your.package.Product).class}">
  <h2 th:text="${product.get(0, class)}" />
</div>
```

`product.get(qProduct.title)`

```
<!-- For this, you need to add qProduct on the model -->
<div th:each="product :${products}">
  <h2 th:text="${product.get(qProduct.title)}" />
</div>
```

You could also possibly use toArray() as well, though I'm not entirely sure how that would turn out:

```
<div th:each="product :${products}" th:with="data=${product.toArray()}">
  <h2 th:text="${data[0]}" />
</div>
```

Comment: thanks, is correct your answer, it solved mi problem